# Abrir y leer archivos de un servidor por SSH desde python y paramiko

Tags: python, ssh

Tengo un script que conecta a un servidor por SSH, necesito leer ciertos archivos que están en `/Raiz/Reportes/` y no he podido lograrlo. Hasta el momento puedo listar todos los archivos que están en esa ruta. El script está en python y estoy usando paramiko para establecer la conexion por SSH.

```
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(host, username="root", password="passwd", port=22)

sftp_client = client.open_sftp()
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('ls -l /Raiz/Reportes/')

for line in stdout:

read_f = stdout.readlines()
for x in read_f:
    reg = x.split('|')

    print reg
```

¿De qué forma puedo ir abriendo cada uno de los archivos que se listan e irlos guardando?

Comment: Paramiko implementa también un [cliente `sftp`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.4/api/sftp.html), que es lo que deberías utilizar para copiar ficheros.

Comment: De echo la implemento para ingresar al directorio, he visto algunas soluciones de copiar los archivos pero lo ideal para mi sería que sólo fuera, leyera los archivos y guardara la información. ¿Existe alguna forma para hacer eso o la opción que me das de copiar los archivos es la unica?

Comment: No entiendo... ¿quieres únicamente obtener un listado? ¿O quieres los contenidos de los ficheros? Porque si es lo segundo, tendrás que abrirlos para leerlos y recibir su contenido, y para eso sirve `sftp`. Con su método `file()` puedes abrir un fichero en la otra máquina como si fuera local, es decir, que puedes después hacer `read()` de su contenido.

Comment: Exacto, sólo quiero abrir los ficheros, leer su contenido y guardar ese contenid en una DB.

Answer (score 1):

Aquí tienes un sencillo ejemplo de cómo usar Paramiko para establecer una conexión con el servidor SSH y usar esa conexión para leer una serie de ficheros (en este caso he elegido leer los que tengan extensión `.c`). En este ejemplo me limito a leer los contenidos para mostrar cuántos bytes tienen, pero puedes hacer lo que necesites con el contenido, una vez leido.

```
import paramiko

# Abrir el transporte

host = "ip.de.tu.servidor"
port = 22
transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))

# Autenticarse en el servidor
# SOLO COMO DEMO, NUNCA SE DEBEN PONER CLAVES EN EL CÓDIGO

username = "usuario"
password = "contraseña"
transport.connect(username = username, password = password)

# Creación del canal sftp

sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)

# Recorrer los ficheros existentes en el home del usuario
for name in sftp.listdir("."):
    if name.endswith(".c"):
        # Si termina en .c, lo leemos
        with sftp.file(name) as f:
            data = f.read()
            # Mostramos cuántos bytes hemos leido
            print(f"El fichero {name} tiene {len(data)} bytes")

# Cerrar el canal y después el transporte
sftp.close()
transport.close()
```

Comment: Modifiqué un poco el código de esta manera pero me aparece un error de "No such file" ¿Qué es lo que tiene mal?

Comment: `name` te da solo el nombre del fichero, pero si no está en la carpeta actual, para abrirlo debes concatenarle la ruta en que se encuentre. O cambiarte a la carpeta adecuada con `sftp.chdir()`